# Tying to style Vuetify data table so that sorting arrows are always on the same line as header - not under?

Tags: css, vue.js, datatable, vue-component, vuetify.js

In the Vuetify data table, when the header is long, the sorting arrows appear under the header. I am trying to get the sorting arrows in the header to always appear on the same line as the header.

**Here is my data table:**

```
<v-data-table
      :headers="headers"[![enter image description here][2]][2]
      :items="truncatedRows"
      :items-per-page="5"
      class="elevation-1"
 ></v-data-table>
```

**What I'm getting:**

[image]

**What I'd like no matter the length of the headers:**

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `headers` Array item's object, you can add a `width` value, e.g `width: 6rem`.

You could also add another key/value pair here to add a custom CSS class via `class: 'my-header-name'`. This would allow you to further customize the display, such as using `display: flex; align-items: center` which works kind of nicely depending upon your expectations.

Utilizing and experimenting with these methods, you should be able to get close to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 13):

```
.v-data-table-header th {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/10164

Answer (score 0):

None of the existing answers worked for me, unfortunately, so I did the following instead:

```css
.v-data-table-header th .v-data-table-header__icon {
  display: none;
}
```

and then added my own `<v-icon>` arrow inside the header slots.